# How do I start mongodb in a different terminal using a script in mac?

Tags: bash, mongodb, macos, shell, terminal

I am using a macbook. I have this app, where I have to execute a few commands after starting mongodb in a different terminal, keep it running and then I have to execute my commands in the terminal I have run script.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Could you please explain your question clearly?

Comment: Why do you need to start MongoDB in a different terminal - can't you start it in the current terminal but just in the background by adding `&` to the end of the command you use to start it?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I want to monitor how many connections are made to mongodb. So I want it running in another terminal. And it makes it harder to kill the process whenever I want, if it is running in background!

Comment: @HasanAlperOcalan: When I execute ./mongod, it takes few secs and it will be waiting for connections in the terminal. When the mongod is waiting for connections, I want to open a new terminal and execute another command, let's say echo Hello. Can I do that?

Comment: @PranoyTez Yes you can. When your mongod is working in first terminal tab, press cmd+T and new terminal tab will be opened. You can do whatever you want to do in this new tab.

Comment: Or Cmd+N for a new window

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I know that command, but I want to implement in a script so that It does the work instead of me typing the command?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this, maybe in a shell script or a function:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "start mongodb"'
```

I am not sure what actual command you use to start MongoDB but put that inside the double quotes.

Of course, you can make this a function in your login script:

```
function startmongo(){
   osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "start mongodb"'
}
```

Then you would just need to type:

```
startmongo
```